# C# remoting Tcp канал

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

Я использую remoting для взаимодействия приложений и доменов на уровне `TCP-IPC` (Прошу не ссылаться на WCF, есть причины использования этой технологии). Есть несколько приложений(броудкастеров), создающих свои каналы по разным портам в рамках одной машины:

```
var properties = new Hashtable();
properties ["port"] = port;
properties.Add("name", channelName);
properties.Add("exclusiveAddressUse", false);
var prov= new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider {TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full};
var channel = new TcpChannel(properties , new BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider(), prov);
```

(Каждое приложение открывает собственный канал по этой схеме)

Каждое приложение должно использовать собственное `TCP` соединение для взаимодействия с клиентами. Клиенты подключатся к нужным приложениям и получают данные и осуществляют взаимодействие. 
`TCPViewer` показал, что открываются разные порты для разных приложений-броудкасетров, однако все данные идут через один порт! Изменил флаг `exclusiveAddressUse` на `true`  - не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы каждое приложение-броудкастер транслировало данные через собственное соединение.

Comment: Нет ли у кого экспертизы в этом вопросе?